# code working well in \document{article} fails in {revtex4} when dealing with a table

Tags: tables, xetex, revtex

The .tex file with a table in it works well in `\documentclass{article}` or `\documentclass{ctexart}`, but fails in `\documentclass{\revtex4}`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}

\usepackage{xeCJK}                  
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}


\begin{document}

\section{氢原子}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    hello & hi
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Here is the error message:

```
(f:/Texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(f:/Texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \aftergroup 
l.15 \end{document}
               
?
```

and here is the output in `\documentclass{ctexart}`

[image: output in \documentclass{ctexart}]

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  I see you have TeXLive2014 -- when was it last updated? The reason I ask is because I'm running TeXLive2015 (pre-release version) on my system and experience no problems running your MWE on my system.

Comment: My software was installed last September and has never been updated since, indeed. I have updated all the packages in the past two hours, and it works! Thank you @Mico very much!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that the suggestion to update your TeX distribution and packages was fruitful. I'm going to propose to close this posting -- not because it's somehow "bad" (which it clearly is not!), but simply because we have policy on this site to close postings where the problem stems from out-of-date packages or TeX distributions. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by the presence of an out-of-date package.